# :PluginInstall not a command on vim?

Tags: python, vim, plugins, ide

I am new to using vim as an IDE and I've been trying to get the proper plugins to install a python friendly vim IDE, and somehow it stopped working a couple hours ago, giving me the error:

```
E492: Not an editor command: PluginInstall
```

Is there any way this can be fixed?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, Vim built-in commands usually begin with a lower-case letter. Most commands which begin with  an upper-case letter are user commands, defined interactively or in a script file.

In particular, the command `:PluginInstall` is not a built-in Vim command; as far as I call tell it is defined by a third party plugin manager such as [`Vundle`](https://github.com/VundleVim/Vundle.vim). Use the documentation which came with your plugin manager to find out how to load it into Vim.